# How do I write a csv file by taking Cassandra's table as an input using Spark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, apache-spark, cassandra

If the scale of data is massive and evergrowing, how do I write data into CSV file from Cassandra's table using Spark? The issue is of scale, not running into any infra related issues because of my own code; hence, asking for well-tested tools and methods. On a similar note, is spark the best choice as far as speed is concerned?

The table schema in Cassandra is:

```
c_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version int, row varchar, row_hash varchar, PRIMARY KEY((version), id))".format(
            self.table_name
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reading data into dataframe you can use Datastax Spark-Cassandra connector. Here is a link with examples how to read data from Cassandra into dataframe: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

```
daraframe=spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="kv", keyspace="test")\
    .load()
```

Then you can just write data into csv:

```
dataframe.write.csv('/path/to/file.csv')
```

Comment: Loading a billion rows of data won't cause my OOM errors? Also, from where did you get `dataframe`?

Comment: @aviralsanjay 1. About OOM it depends on configuration of your spark cluster and application, but as usual Spark splits computation into a lot of tasks that are executed separately on one or multiple nodes. 2. Fixed code in answer making it more clear